# Android Chrome browser overlays soft keyboard over webpage covering input fields

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, html

I have this problem on an HTML5 app.  It works perfectly fine with Safari and Chrome on iOS, but the problem occurs on Android devices.

Whenever a form with input fields is displayed and I try to enter any details, the soft keyboard covers the fields, instead of shifting them up.  On smaller devices, like phones, it is impossible to see what you are typing.

I need to add that this is even worse when running the app added to home screen, in full screen mode.  The keyboard just overlays everything.

I have tried every 'solution' online, but to no avail.  Please note, this is not for a native app, but an online website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have the same issue on Android 6, while using the WeChat browser.

Comment: How has this not been answered? Did you ever resolve the issue?

Comment: @MikePurcell - no it hasn't been answered and I ran into the issue again recently.  It happens on Android when in standalone mode, it seems that it is fine when the browser is not standalone.

Comment: Ahhh that sucks. I found my issue to be because I am implementing fullpage js. Are you?

Comment: Check this out, it may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516968/android-keyboard-covering-input-box-even-in-chrome-browser/39537597#39537597